# form doesn't work after use render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I trying to use render method inside my activeAdmin form method, but after insert render
in code, it stopped to work.

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs I18n.t('sale_header') do
      f.input :client
      f.input :room
    end

    f.inputs I18n.t('sale_items')  do
      render :partial => "form_sale"
    end

    f.inputs I18n.t('totalization') do
      f.input :sub_total, :input_html => { :disabled => :true }
      f.input :discount
      f.input :total_value, :input_html => { :disabled => :true }
    end

    f.buttons
end
```

After insert the render method, only form_sale content is showed on screen.

Any help?
Thank You!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html) , the right way to customize the form in active_admin is :

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  form :partial => "form"
end
```

and then in your partial "_form.html.erb" you should use [formtastic DSL](http://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) , something like this:

```
 <%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @post] do |f| %>
   <%= f.inputs :title, :body %>
   <%= f.buttons :commit %>
 <% end %>
```

On the web page is clearly stated :

```
If you require a more custom form than can be provided through the DSL, you can pass 
a partial in to render the form yourself.
```

which means , that the DSL of active_admin has some slight limitations .

All my experiments with 'render' and 'form :partial' has finished with no result . If you'd like to use partial , it should replace all the form .

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem in one project. I just did what @Qumara said, write the entire form in the partial with formtastic.

Comment: Wait, so if you need a tiny bit of raw html you have to toss the DSL and rewrite the page? Sigh. The more I work with it, the more the ActiveAdmin seems like a hindrance rather than a help… Leaning toward plain bootstrap admin interfaces.

Comment: Currently ActiveAdmin's support is not the best one. Bootstrap interfaces seems to be a nice option.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using form :partial => "form" in a lot of cases and this is definitely the way to go when you want custom forms.

This answer is not here to be accepted as the correct one but sometimes I do not want to make an ERB partial and I just want to add some content to an almost perfect AA generated form.

for those times I use this trick, I add a content method to AA FormBuilder with this initializer :

```
ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder.class_eval do
  def content
    form_buffers.last << with_new_form_buffer do
        yield
    end
  end
end
```

And then I can use f.content() in my AA form block :

```
  form do |f|
    f.content do content_tag(:p, "Hello world!") end
      f.inputs do
        f.input :foo
        f.input :bar
      end
      f.content do content_tag(:p, "Hello world!") end
      f.buttons
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `render` this actually renders the entire response. Assuming you're trying to nest this, try `render_to_string`. Although I'm not entirely certain what you have in form_sale and whether that's what you want in that block.

Comment: undefined method `render_to_string' for #<ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::Form:

Comment: `ActionController::Base.new().render_to_string(partial:` … worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Qumara is right.  Still, monkeypatches to the active admin ~ formtastic dsl bridge are possible. What worked for me is opening up the ActiveAdmin::Formbuilder class in the config/initializers/active_admin.rb file. There I added:

```
class ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder
  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
  def custom_capture_text content
    form_buffers.last << template.content_tag(:li,content.html_safe)
  end
```

end

Then you can write

```
f.inputs I18n.t('sale_items')  do
  f.custom_capture_text(f.template.render(:partial => "form_sale"))
end
```

This worked in activeadmin 0.3 through 0.5. But beware. ActiveAdmin upgrade might break it. Good luck.